# SUM for MONTH() not being calculated properly

Tags: mysql, date, sum

In my code, I get the number of rows present for the following times:

Today   Yesterday   2 Days Ago  3 Days Ago  4 Days Ago  5 Days Ago  6 Days Ago  7 Days Ago  This Week   This Month  Last Month  This Year

Now every single time is working great, except for "This Month". It seems that this is not being calculated properly. Here is my SQL:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select `website`, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_day, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_yesterday, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_2_days, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_3_days, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_4_days, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_5_days, 
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_6_days,
                    sum(case when DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_7_days,
                    sum(case when WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = WEEK(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_week, 
                    sum(case when MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_month,
                    sum(case when MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_last_month,
                    sum(case when YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = YEAR(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_year
                    from `assignments`
                    where `id_dealership`!='65' and `id_dealership`!='77' and `id_dealership`!='89'
                    group by `website`
                    order by `website` asc
                    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

So as you can see, `c_month` is what is causing me problems. I have no clue why this is happening considering c_last_month is working flawlessly.

EDIT AGAIN:

Heres the table structure and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assignments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_dealership` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_lead` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_assigned` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `make` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_dealership` (`id_dealership`),
  KEY `id_lead` (`id_lead`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9848 ;


(1165, 40, 1373, 1325540129, 'website.com', 'Ford', 'Edge', ''),
(1164, 34, 1372, 1325539601, 'website.com', 'Ford', 'F-350', ''),
(1163, 34, 1371, 1325537245, 'website.com', 'Ford', 'Focus', ''),
(1162, 34, 1370, 1325529221, 'website.com', 'Ford', 'Flex', ''),
```

Comment: Actually, we can't see.  You've not shown us the data or the output (just the output headings).  Please reduce your code to an SSCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Complete (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/)).  For example, we only need to see today, yesterday, and maybe 7 days ago, plus the month ones that are not working.  Then your output might fit across one line without the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I've added my PHP code. I hope this helps you help me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how's the performance of your script? (Perhaps run `EXPLAIN` on the query) Somehow I get a feeling that the performance will be just terrible with large amount of records.

Comment: I was looking for the SQL data — the table schema, some sample data, the expected output, the actual output, and why it is wrong — not further PHP.  The problem is in the SQL more than in the PHP.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, I edited it one more time with what you requested.

Comment: But still no output.  What part of c_month isn't working?  As @Vyktor points out, performance will degrade as the table grows.  I would suggest a summary table.

Comment: I would store dates in `DATE` or `DATETIME` columns in a database, so you can actually use them in calculations without having to convert them first. That will speed up the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLs [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) returns current month from date. This means your condition in script is matching only:

- on `2012-10-01` - 1 day
- on `2012-10-05` - 5 days
- on `2012-10-30` - 30 days (**correct**)

So your script is working correctly once a month on a last day :) and you're displaying "*number of views since the beginning of this month*".

So you basically just need to replace condition

```sql
sum(case when MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) =
    MONTH(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_month
```

With this one (which would count items from last 31 days):

```sql
SUM(CASE (`date_assigned` > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_month
```

---

One more thing, I'd be worried about your performance. I would count summary info in separate table (or add columns into existing table) and use pre-calculated data and refresh them with script (executed via cron or so).

If you require data to be accurate, add index on `date_assigned` (or rather on `id_dealership, date_added`) and extend condition with:

```sql
AND `date_added` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

To process only records one year old (and no more).

Answer (score 0):

Your condition

```
sum(case when MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = MONTH(CURDATE())
     then 1 else 0 end) AS c_month,
```

should not be used because it will not return the correct information once your database contains more information.

```
MONTH('2011-11-14') = MONTH('2012-11-04') = MONTH('2013-11-24')
```

If you want to show statistics of This Month, you should check both MONTH() and YEAR(). This month is not just November, it is November 2012.

The same also goes for Last Month.